# How to load PDF/Images from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Currently, I display images in my app using `Firestore RecyclerView`. The app retrieves URL from `Cloud Firestore`, which contain links for images saved in `Firebase Storage`. However, this method is very time-consuming as I have to create entries (URL) in the `Cloud Firestore` for every image I saved in `Firebase Storage`.

One advantage to this is when the user taps on one image, I could send only that one image to a `DialogFragment` with `com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView` in the layout that the user could zoom in/out, without zooming in/out the rest of the images.

If possible, I would like to load directly the images from `Firebase Storage` to a `RecyclerView`, or better yet, load a PDF file (with multiple pages) directly into `RecyclerView`.

I am currently using `GlideApp` for images. I suppose I'll have to use `WebView` for `PDF's (I am about to try it). Some stated on the forums that popular PDF Libraries in Android will add about 16 MB of additional size to the final APK.

Is feeding images into the `RecyclerView` the best option? Is there a PDF Library that provides the same functionality?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Entries, you mean URLs, right? If so, what's the problem with storing URLs?

Comment: are you trying to load pdf thumbnail in RecyclerView?

Comment: @Ramesh If possible render PDF in RecyclerView.